# How to pass an additional json file to chef client

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

We use chef-client to deploy our services. Generally, we pass recipe argument with '--runlist' parameter, and an environment json like 'dev_env.json' using '-E' parameter.

```
chef-client --local-mode --logfile /dev/stdout --log_level info --config /etc/chef/client.rb -E dev_env --runlist 'recipe[Service1]'
```

Now we have another json which we cannot make part of dev_env.json', this json also has configurations like environment json but still need to be kept separate. Is there any way I can also pass this json to my chef recipe alongwith the dev_env.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two options are either make it into node attributes (through `-j` or making it in to a role) or make it into a data bag item by placing it at `./data_bags/whatever/itemname.json`.